# Restangular pass HTTP Request Methods as parameter

Tags: restangular

I am new to restangular and angular

we have a function that looks like

```
function (service_url, method){

$http({
    url: service_url,
            method: method,
            data: {


    },
    headers: {

    }
    })
```

}

as you can see the method is being passed by the caller of this function I need the same functionality in restangular any help will be appreciated kindly excuse my lack of knowledge

Comment: do you want to use dynamic method?

Comment: Yes something where in I am able to make a get or post call on the resource by passing a flag

Comment: ok then, I assume you will create a restangular service which can receive url and method type as a parameter?

Comment: yes thats what I am doing but dont know how I will pass the method type to restangular @ runtime

Comment: a plunker would be really helpful

Comment: and my basic question is does restangular provide such a functionality ?

Comment: yes it can but maybe you can develop better approaches by the help of angular... I will create a plunker for you when I will have time...